# Matplotlib and seaborn color palette don't match

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to plot a dataframe from 2 perspectives and I'm using matplotlib for one and seaborn for the other just because it's easier this way. My problem is that I can't make the colormap match for both plots. Here's a simple reproducible code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
cat = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:25]
n_times = 5
df_list = []
for i in range(n_times):
    df_list.append( pd.DataFrame({ 'category': cat, 'time': i, 'value':  np.random.uniform(size=(25,)) * 1000}) )
df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
df['category'] = pd.Categorical( df['category'], ordered=True, categories=cat )

# matplotlib
ax = df.pivot(index = 'time', columns='category', values='value').plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, colormap='tab20c')

# seaborn
fig, ax = plt.subplots();
sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_palette("tab20c", n_colors=25)
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="time", y='value', hue='category', style='category', ax=ax);
```

Here's how both plot looks like:

[image: matplotlib]

[image: seaborn]

The problem I have is that I have 25 categories. I settled with the 'tab20c' colormap to better display the colors. As you can see, the colors for the matplotlib and seaborn plot don't match. Under matplotlib, I get 5 shades for each color (blue, orange, green, purple, gray) while under seaborn, I only get 4 shades, thus the colors get recycled.

How can I fix this?

Also, I am having a hard time maneuvering seaborn. If I use set_palette("tab20c") only, without specifying n_colors, it uses a totally different color scheme. Is there a reason why?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Well, more than about 12 colors are very hard to distinguish in a plot.  `tab20c` has only 20 colors.  With `sns.set_palette("tab20c", n_colors=25)`, some of the intermediate colors are taken twice. With `df.plot(kind='bar', colormap='tab20c', ...)` the colors are taken one by one, and the last five repeat.  You could do `df.plot(...., cmap=sns.color_palette('tab20c', n_colors=25, as_cmap=True))` to get the same repetition in the pandas plot.  Or use a continuous colormap, e.g. `'turbo`.

Comment: It looks like your "matplotlib" (actually pandas) palette is also getting recycled, just in a different order from the seaborn plot.